# What is the correct formula to position my scroll bar slider?

Tags: c++

This slider is used in my rpg to get rid of X amount of items so at pos 1 it will junk 1 item at max pos it will junk all the items.

slider image

[image]

My current formula is not correct

```
int pos_int = std::ceil(106.00 / (double)amount);
int base_pos = 318 - (amount - this->dj_slider_pos) * pos_int;
```

122 pixels is the total width of the draw area but after considering the width of the slider is 16 pixels the last draw position is at 106 pixels. Amount is the total number of items you have and dj_slider_pos tracks the position of the slider.
I have tried a few different variations but figured I might as well try and get help here instead of continuing to spin my wheels. Here is a little more code.

```
int amount = 1;
std::string itname = "";
UTIL_PTR_VECTOR_FOREACH(this->character->inventory_items,Character_Item,it)
{
    if(it->id == this->character_inventory->selected_id)
    {
        itname = util::ucfirst(this->world->eif->Get(it->id)->name);
        amount = it->amount;
        break;
    }
}

int pos_int = std::ceil(106.00 / (double)amount);
int base_pos = 318 - (amount - this->dj_slider_pos) * pos_int;

if(base_pos < 212) base_pos = 212;
else if(base_pos > 318) base_pos = 318;

this->DrawSplitBmp(base_pos,165, this->mouse_sliders,this->screen, &drop_junktabs[7]);
```

Problem solved! I initialized dj_slider_pos to 0 instead of 1 and changed the following lines.

```
    double pos_int = 106.00 / (double)(amount-1); 
    int base_pos = 212 + (this->dj_slider_pos * pos_int);
```

Comment: Whats the magic `318`?

Comment: sorry.. 318 is the last horizonal draw position. The first draw position is 212 + 106 = 318. base_pos should be the  top left pixel of the horizonal draw position.

Comment: Looks correct to me, and I just tested it, it does result in the values I expected, you might get some minor problems because `pos_int` is an int, make it a double (and drop the `ceil`) and it should be exact.

Comment: Ok I did what you said and it corrected the issue where there are more items than the width of the draw area(106) but the first draw position is still incorrect I think base_pos calculation is not correct. I didnt mention it but this->dj_slider_pos starts at 1!

Comment: Just subtract 1 from `amount` and `this->dj_slider_pos` in your calculation to make it 0-based.

Comment: Irritation: using values in pixels will make your game unplayable on high-DPI screens.

Comment: For this game I am using SDL and SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI flag so there is no problem with high dpi screens.When high-dpi support is enabled, SDL_GetWindowSize() and display mode sizes will still be in "screen coordinates" rather than pixels.

Comment: @tkausl Thankyou for the help I initialized this->dj_slider_pos = 0 and changed double pos_int = 106.00 / (double)(amount-1); and the slider is working as desired!

Comment: Too many magic numbers.